# Add JS Library to Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome Extension and I am having trouble adding a JavaScript library to use in my content script.

I am trying to add the [Mutation Summary Library](https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/).  I put the 'mutation_summary.js' file into the extension's directory and I tried to add it by adding 'mutation_summary.js' to the 'manifest.json' file as shown below:

```
"content_scripts": [
    { 
      "matches": ["http://soundcloud.com/*", "https://soundcloud.com/*"],
      "js": ["content_script.js", "mutation_summary.js"]
    }
```

An extension error is thrown when I add it.  The errors says "Could not load javascript 'mutation_summary.js' for content script.

Am I adding the javascript library incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: Please remove the google-chrome-app tag.

Comment: Could you please post the file structure for your extension?

Comment: All the files are together in the same folder.  There are no subfolders.  So the content_script.js, background.js, and mutation_sumary.js files are all at the same level in the same folder

Comment: As a side note you'll want to put the `mutation_summary.js` file first in the array. They get executed from left to right.

Comment: Triple-check file names. You yourself just called it "sumary"

Comment: @mgeno `mutation_summary` is spelled with two "m's in "summary". Double-check whether your spelling is correct.

Comment: @Thouartamazing web_accessible_resources is of no use here. Content scripts should usually not be declared web_accessible.

Answer (score -1):

It works perfectly for me. I created an extension with a file called mutation_summary.js which contains `console.log('FILE LOADED!');` and it shows up as soon as I load soundcloud.com, maybe you had a typo with the file name?

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://soundcloud.com/*", "https://soundcloud.com/*"],
            "js":["mutation_summary.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```